# Class 'Crypto\Cipher' not found error while performing aes decryption in php

Tags: php, aes

I am performing AES Decryption in PHP. 
I have Used These libraries.

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
use Crypto\CMAC;
use Crypto\Cipher;
```

I am getting an error in this line.

```
$cipher = Cipher::aes(Cipher::MODE_ECB, 128);
```

Do i need to install any extension/library for windows to perform the decryption

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Crypto\Cipher' not found in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\demo4.php</b> on line <b>88</b><br />

Comment: So where's your class `Crypto\Cipher`?

Comment: *I have Used These libraries.* - What libraries?

Comment: From the namespace are you trying to use: https://github.com/bukka/php-crypto? If so installation is on the readme.

Comment: Yes @LawrenceCherone I was searching for the same